# How to know if my booking is complete?

Tags: soap, sabre

I use REST API Instaflights and SOAP API book air segment to book the flights, so after the book process with SOAP API how to know if my booking is successful ?

Is there any GUI dashboard to know booking complete or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if your creating a Booking/Trip/PNR, if the transaction was successful and completed, you would received back a Sabre Record Locator that is used for confirmation.

Which services are you consuming to complete the Booking?